# Show more content with click in different stages

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have following setup:

```
<div class="uncode-post-table">
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  ...
</div>
<a id="more-actions" onclick="event.preventDefault();" href="javascript:void(0);">Load more actions</a>
```

The list with the div.tmb will be extended by time, for now it contains 50 items.

In my CSS I have following line:

```
.uncode-post-table .tmb:nth-child(n+11) {
  display: none;
}
```

So it shows only the first ten .tmb div's. What I want to do when I click the link is to appear the next 10 .tmb div's in the list (so .tmb div 1-20 will show up). Another click on the link will show another 10 .tmb div's (1-30). And so on, until all div's are visible.

So far I have this in jQuery:

```
$("#more-actions").click(function(){
  $(".uncode-post-table .tmb").css("display", "block");
});
```

This will show all the .tmb div's at once when the link is clicked.

I tried to find an answer here: [Show more / show less with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128483/show-more-show-less-with-jquery), it also shows the whole list instead of the next 10 div's.
Also this one doesn't really answer my question: [Whats the best way to implement a "Show More" button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108186/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-show-more-button-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the next 10 and so on, after each click you can do it like this:

```
$("#more-actions").click(function() {
  $(".uncode-post-table .tmb:visible:last").nextAll("*:lt(10)").css("display", "block");
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#more-actions").click(function() {
  $(".uncode-post-table .tmb:visible:last").nextAll("*:lt(10)").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.uncode-post-table .tmb:nth-child(n+11) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uncode-post-table">
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
  <div class="tmb">some content</div>
</div>
<a id="more-actions" onclick="event.preventDefault();" href="javascript:void(0);">Load more actions</a>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, thank you so much!